# Is there an R function that can identify duplicate rows in a dataframe and classify them if "x" if found in any of those rows?

Tags: r, filter, duplicates

I am working on a project in R studio that deals with a large database on information that is riddled with duplicates. I work in environmental science and have only a basic understanding of coding, I have mostly used R for data analysis. I have found ways to sift out these duplicates, but the problem comes where there are certain classifications that may or may not actually be duplicates and I want to separate these rows of data to check by hand.

Basically I am looking at bird causes of admission to rehabilitation centers, and can find which are duplicates if they have the same values for Date 1 and Date 2. However baby birds will sometimes look like duplicates because multiple can be admitted at one time. Below is a basic example of what my dataframe looks like;

| Species | Date 1 | Cause | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue Jay | 01-05 | UNK | 01-15 |
| Blue Jay | 01-05 | PELVIS | 01-15 |
| Robin | 06-12 | UNK | 06-24 |
| Robin | 06-12 | ORPHAN | 06-24 |
| Robin | 06-12 | UNK | 06-24 |
| Robin | 06-12 | ORPHAN | 06-24 |

Here the Blue Jay is presumably an adult and should only appear once, however I want the Robin Rows all identified separately for me to check. How can I group the baby bird rows if only some of them contain "ORPHAN" as a cause?

I tried filtering out all the duplicates of the dataframe and then pulling rows with "ORPHAN" in Cause, but this leaves behind rows that should be grouped with them, such as the 3rd and 5th rows above with "UNK" listed.

Edit; Thank you all so much for your feedback! I think my desired outcome for this problem would be to end up with two new columns added to the dataframe, one to count and group all rows with the same species, date 1, and date 2 (i.e. OID's = 1.1 and 1.2 for the jay rows, and 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and 2.4 for the robin rows), and one that identifies whether or not these 'groups' are baby birds (i.e. Baby = true, or Baby = false). I am still not entirely sure what I want to do to consolidate the duplicate rows as of right now, but have been inspired by some of your suggestions. For reference I could go through and hand check all the data, but there are 60,000+ rows and would like to find a more efficient way before investing in such and endeavor.

Comment: Can you include (and/or clarify) exactly which rows should be retained? I donp't understand how "ORPHAN" is supposed to change the de-duplication logic.

Comment: Can you please be more exact in what you want done? How do you know a baby bird from an adult - is it whether or not "orphan" is listed as a "cause"? If so, it sounds like you want to identify rows where the Species, Date 1, and Date 2 values are the same and none of the Cause values are "ORPHAN" and collapse them into a single row. Is that a good description?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Thea Tengstrom! This is a good start at a first question! The sample data is great (it's not hard to use, but some ppl may also prefer to have the output from `dput(head(x))` where `x` is your data.frame ... the reason is less critical here, but embedded spaces can be onerous to parse into a frame, and we don't always know what the `class` of some columns are from this). For questions, it is also equally important to provide unambiguous _expected output_, often in the same format (a frame/table). Thank you!

Comment: If the 2 Blue Jay rows are to be collapsed into 1 row, what should the Cause value be? I assume "UNK" means unknown, and you want to keep "PELVIS" in this case, but what if there are two different Causes that are both not "UNK"?  What if there are multiple "UNK" rows for the same Species and Date columns?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this?:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Species, `Date 1`, `Date 2`) %>%
    mutate(Check = ifelse("ORPHAN" %in% Cause, paste(sort(Cause), collapse = ", "), NA)) %>%
    ungroup()%>%
    select(-Cause) %>%
    distinct()

Species  `Date 1` `Date 2` Check                   
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                   
1 Blue Jay 01-05    01-15    NA                      
2 Robin    06-12    06-24    ORPHAN, ORPHAN, UNK, UNK
```